# Tunneling in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-tunneling

Tunneling in QM is well defined phenomenon since for a real potential the number of particles remain constant. But when we switch to field theory the number of particles need not to remain constant though the number is well defined at an instant of time $\hat{N}=\Sigma a^{\dagger}_ka_k$. Moreover, there is nothing to tunnel as such since field  permeates everywhere in the spacetime.

Though if used the concept of tunneling a bit more generally or abstractly I think we can say field tunnels from phase A to phase B. Since I don't know about condensed matter using field technique this idea may be totally wrong as well.

I think my above example may clarify what I'm looking for: is concept of tunneling defined in QFT? If yes, how?